# Liferay 7 - Simplest way to consume a REST webservice doesnt work

Tags: java, web-services, rest, liferay, osgi-bundle

I am simply not able to invoke a REST webservice from Liferay 7.
I created a REST module using Eclipse and it gave me the following entries in *build.gradle* by default :

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0.1'
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version: "1.3.0"
}
```

Code to invoke the REST webservice :

```
String uri = "http://RestServiceURL";
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(uri);       
        String result = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .get().readEntity(String.class);
```

The error when I deploy and invoke the REST service :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder cannot be found by com.liferay.portal.remote.cxf.common_2.0.6
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:349)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:115)
at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:225)
at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
... 110 more
```

I tried adding the following entry to *build.gradle*

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.21'
```

Is there any specific entries to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Are you importing the packages in you bnd.bnd file? If yes, can you try the option "**resolution:=optional**"? It should solve your problem.

For example, you should write the following in your bnd.bnd:

Import-Package:
com.sun.jersey.api.json;resolution:=optional; \
com.sun.jersey.core.header;resolution:=optional;

Please take a note that you may have to change the package names as per your requirement, above mentioned is just an example.

I hope you have already referred to OSGi Module Dependency blog:
https://web.liferay.com/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies

If you can share the content of bnd.bnd, that will be more helpful.